# Watt meter connection in three phase circuit

Tags: three-phase, power-measurement

Does the zero point "where all the voltage coils are linked " in this watt meter connection indicates that the power measured by each one of the watt meter is the phase to neutral or the phase to phase power?

[image]

Comment: There is no neutral in your schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... phase to neutral or the phase to phase power?

Assuming a balanced load:

It measures the power delivered or consumed on that phase. Even if the load is connected in Delta it still measures the power on that phase because the √3 times the voltage (between phases) is multiplied by 1/√3 due to the phase angle and the product is 1.

For an unbalanced load:

Take the cases where one of the ***Z***s is open or short circuit then ***N<sub>L</sub>*** will no longer be at the centre (star or wye point). The individual meter readings still tell you what power is being delivered by each phase but don't tell you **where** it is being consumed. The sum of the meters gives the total power consumed by the load.

Comment: this makes perfect sense , but i want to point to an additional clarification , since the watt meter use high impedance voltage coil to measure the voltage then  the voltage drop will be at maximum , hence difference between the phase voltage and the voltage drop is equal to 0 v , and that what makes it a single phase power measurement .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the point you are making.